# Export Worksheet to PDF on different pages

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export, area

I´d like to safe the area A1 to BJ10 in a PDF Document. Since this area is quite wide, I´d like to split the parts on three pages.
A1:R10, S1:BB10 and BC1:BJ10.

my current code is:

```
Sub ToPDF()
    
    Sheets(1).PageSetup.Orientation = 2
    
    Sheets(1).PageSetup.Zoom = False
    Sheets(1).PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:BJ10").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=Path, Openafterpublish:=True
End Sub
```

How can I safe the mentioned area as PDF where every part of the area has it´s own page?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to copy ranges to a temporary workbook then each sheet is a separate page.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ToPDF()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim ar, i As Long, sFilename As String

    ' ranges
    ar = Array("A1:R10", "S1:BB10", "BC1:BJ10")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    sFilename = "ranges.pdf"
    With wbTemp
        For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
            If i > 0 Then .Worksheets.Add after:=.Sheets(i)
            With .Sheets(i + 1)
                .PageSetup.Orientation = 2
                .PageSetup.Zoom = False
                .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
                ws.Range(ar(i)).Copy .Range("A1")
            End With
        Next
        .ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=sFilename, Openafterpublish:=True
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you!
this is exactly what I was looking for!